Convert to TeX-2-Word using TeX4ht and Pandoc - AMSTHM problem
I tried with:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{theorem}
This is the test content for Theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}

I run the command htlatex test "xhtml", which converts to HTML format; and the output HTML was:

after that I tried with
pandoc -s test.html -o test.docx

which converted to Word format, but the content of the Theorem changed to roman, and the head Theorem changed from Bold to Roman, how can I get as like as TeX output, i.e., Head in Bold and the text in Italic


that is not a latex question, but a pandoc problem.

Covert to Word directly with Pandoc: pandoc -f latex -t docx test.tex -o test.docx.

Convert to Word directly with TeX4ht: make4ht -f odt test.tex

@michal.h21 and @Fran; I need the Math in OML format in Word file, because of the reason, I'm using Pandoc, please advise

I have no idea about Word and OML format (Linux\LaTeX user for a long time), but both methods convert the maths of latex into something editable in the formula editor of LibreOffice, so ...

You can convert the generated ODT file to DOCX using Pandoc, Libre Office or Word. I think it will use OML format for math in any case.

@michal.h21 I tried with the suggestion what you said (make4ht and Pandoc), but still the said Bold and Italic problem for the Theorem doesn't solve, but got the equations into OML format
